# Running a Tor middle relay or bridge with 100 GB bandwidth/month?

Tags: debian, tor, vps

I have a VPS running Debian with bandwidth limited to 100 GB per month.I was thinking of running a Tor Network relay on it,since most of that bandwidth goes unused.I don't want it to be an exit node, so I was going to set a normal relay, but I saw in the FAQ that you should run a bridge if you don't want to be an exit and/or have little bandwidth.

So my question is, with those resources,and being able to dedicate at least 80 of those 100 GB monthly to the relay, which would be the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You my very well run a relay, given your limitations. A Tor exit `may` be a hassle, you should do it only if you are willing to accept inquiries by your ISP, angry people claiming you are spamming them, and so on.

As for the difference between a relay and a bridge, it is entirely up to you. The amount of bandwidth you are willing to dedicate to the service may be passed on to the Tor configuration file, `/etc/tor/torrc`, which in fact states:

> Use these to restrict the maximum traffic per day, week, or month.
> Note that this threshold applies separately to sent and received bytes,
> not to their sum: setting "4 GB" may allow up to 8 GB total before
> hibernating.
>
> Set a maximum of 4 gigabytes each way per period.
>
> ## AccountingMax 4 GB
>
> Each period starts daily at midnight (AccountingMax is per day)
>
> ## AccountingStart day 00:00
>
> Each period starts on the 3rd of the month at 15:00 (AccountingMax
> is per month)
>
> ## AccountingStart month 3 15:00

You may thus limit the ttal amount of traffic per month, as you see fit. Tor is quite elastic about this, the amount you have to donate is perfectly fine.

Comment: I've managed to get it running, but in the log it constantly complains about the the time differing from their server's.My VPS provider uses OpenVZ so I can't use NTP or change the date/time at all.Reading about it it seems that it requires time to be synchronised even when being used as a client (if I understood correctly) and in other OSes too.However I usually use the Tor Browser in Windows with my local time without a problem.What can I do?